# what git command should be used to remove prior git info

Tags: git, git-clone

I have made a copy ( clone) of a php project and renamed it so that I can use its code as a basis for further development. At this point I've decided not to use git's branch functionality although I understand this may be an option. I'd like to basically perform a new init on this new project's git directory so that there is no memory of the past.

I'm thinking:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD` reverts you to the latest commit, discarding current changes. For your purposes you should remove the `.git` directory from the repo.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `.git` directory in the root of your repo. Git stores everything he knows in there, so removing it will be equal to remove git from this repo. Than you can run `git init` again to change the directory in a git repository.